# Como puedo hacer esto en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

un saludo.

Estoy intentando hacer una integración por API en mi software pero actualmente esta en PHP y la plataforma que intento integrar esta en JavaScript, entonces practicamente debo cambiar estas líneas de código a JavaScript pero no se mucho sobre el tema.

```
public function send_http_request($apikey, $secret, $uri, $method, $data){
            $pwd = hash_hmac('sha1', $method . "|" . $uri . "|" . $data, $secret);

            $options = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                                "Authorization: Hmac " . base64_encode($apikey . ":" . $pwd),
                    'method' => $method,
                    'content' => $data
                )
            );

            $context = stream_context_create($options);

            return file_get_contents($uri, false, $context);
        }
```

Básicamente las líneas reciben el apikey, el secret, la URL y los datos.
Luego con el hash_hmac lo que hago es encriptar.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar me seria de gran utilidad.

Comment: Usa la [API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), pero deberías evitar hacerlo en el cliente, porque las credenciales quedarían accesibles para cualquiera con un mínimo de conocimientos.

Comment: Hola Triby muchas gracias por tu respuesta, por otra parte que podria usar para encriptar?

Comment: Probablemente [esta respuesta (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12099138/2412893) sea útil para encriptar.

Comment: Hola, ya la use pero no me funciona por las librerías que tiene.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para agregar el código que llevas, solo así podemos tratar de ayudarte.